# Xamarin - Package Manager Console error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional` with `Xamarin` (I'm new with `Xamarin`), and when I open the `Package Manager Console` I get the error: `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: That seams like a bug in the HockeySDK.UWP nuget. I would manually delete that nuget directory and try to get and install the last version of the Hockey nuget

Comment: Is this solution by any chance available in Github so that we can test it out? If not would be able to share the solution?